# Submit form with Ajax and insert data to MySQL not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to submit a form using PHP and MySQL via Ajax, I am getting alert that form is submitted but no data inserted:

Following my code:

```css
<script>
function myFunction() {
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var faddress = document.getElementById("faddress").value;
var surveyername = document.getElementById("surveyername").value;
var surveyurl = document.getElementById("surveyurl").value;
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'fname1=' + fname + '&phone1=' + phone + '&faddress1=' + faddress + '&surveyername1=' + surveyername + '&surveyurl1=' + surveyurl;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
 alert("Form Submitted");
}
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <label>Name :</label>
  <input id="fname" type="text"><br>
  <label>Phone :</label>
  <input id="phone" type="text">
  <label>Address :</label><br>
  <input id="faddress" type="text">
  <label>Surveyer Name :</label><br>
  <input id="surveyername" type="text">
  <input id="surveyurl" type="hidden" value="survey-url"><br>
  <input id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="button" value="Submit">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg custom-back-color" onclick="myFunction()">Submit form</button>
</div>
<!-- PHP code -->
<?php
// Fetching Values From URL
$fname2 = $_POST['fname1'];
$phone2 = $_POST['phone1'];
$faddress2 = $_POST['faddress1'];
$surveyername2 = $_POST['surveyername1'];
$surveyurl2 = $_POST['surveyurl1'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass"); // Establishing Connection with Server..
if($connection === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO form_element (fname, phone, faddress, surveyername, surveyurl) VALUES ('$fname2', '$phone2', '$faddress2','$surveyername2','$surveyurl2')";
if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE TABLE form_element(
 fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 phone varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 faddress varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 surveyername varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 surveyurl varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You should provide the table definition too, e.g. the `CREATE TABLE...` syntax, for anyone wishing to test your code.

Comment: try `<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg custom-back-color"`

Comment: @NikhilGhuse I do not have form tag so still input type button required?

Comment: If you are posting through ajax, you should always use a button/input of type "button".

Comment: Important: What's the name of the file in which your both code snippets reside?

Comment: @dakis file name is survey.php

Comment: So all scripts reside in "survey.php", but you post to a page named "index.php"? That's bad. It should be so, that your js/css/html reside in a "page1.php" and the php script (for inserting in the db) in a separate page "page2.php", which returns the response to be further handled by the ajax request. And never post through ajax to the same page in which the ajax method is called.

Comment: use `JSON.stringify({data: dataString})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,it's bad practice to write parameter directly into your sql,it might led to **SQL Injection**,you had better use **[preparestatement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)** to set the parameter.

Just for your problem,the reason is that,you have not pass the parameter directly to the sql

change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO form_element (fname, phone, faddress, surveyername, surveyurl)
 VALUES ('$fname2', '$phone2', '$faddress2','$surveyername2','$surveyurl2')";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO form_element (fname, phone, faddress, surveyername, surveyurl) 
     VALUES ('".$fname2."', '".$phone2."', '".$faddress2."','".$surveyername2."','".$surveyurl2."')";
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, I tried this but unfortunately dont see any record updated in PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @SanjeevKumar have you checked the output in the log?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar it must have output in the log,since you have written `echo` in your code,you need to find where is the `echo` output,otherwise,there is something wrong in other place of your code

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error on page on load `ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO form_element (fname, phone, faddress, surveyername, surveyurl) VALUES ('', '', '','','').
`

Comment: @SanjeevKumar then check the value of `$fname2`,`$phone2` and so on